# LINQ Query - Find objects in a list who's lists contain objects with a certain property

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I have this struct with two properties:

```
public struct RoomExit
{
    public RoomExitType Type;
    public bool isOccupied;
}
```

This room object can have multiple `RoomExit` structs:

```
public class Room : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RoomExit> Exits;
}
```

In a separate class, I have a list of Room objects:

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> Rooms;
}
```

I want to fashion a LINQ query that searches the `List<GameObject> Rooms` list for Room objects that have a `RoomExit` in their `Exits` list that is of a certain type (let's say RoomExitType.A). I think this is called a subquery but I am not sure.

This is what I have so far:

```
List<GameObject> SelectedRooms = Rooms.Where(x => x.GetComponent<Room>().Exits.Contains(???))
```

I do not understand how to fashion the next part of the query that tries to look if one of the structs in the Exits list has a RoomExitType equal to RoomExitType.A. Here is a visual schematic of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `Any()` LINQ operator:

```
RoomExitType selectedType = RoomExitType.A; // Or RoomExitType.C or whatever
List<GameObject> SelectedRooms = Rooms
    .Where(x => x.GetComponent<Room>().Exits.Any(e => e.Type == selectedType)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = Rooms.Where(room => room.Exits.Any(e => e.Type == RoomExitType.C))
```